# TypeScript Issue: Incorrect Type Inference for discriminated Union of objects

Tags: typescript

```js
// A function that accepts two versions of props: one for an individual and one for an entity.
function Sample(props: { as: "individual", onSubmit: (v: string) => void } | { as: "entity", onSubmit: (v: number) => void }) {

}

const as = "" as "individual" | "entity";

let a = Sample({
    as,
    // The type of 'v' should be string | number and not any.
    onSubmit: (v) => {}
});
```

The type of onsubmit should be onSubmit(v: string)=> void | onSubmit(v: number)=>void

Comment: string | number would suggest than it could be string | number, but it can not(it can be string, it can be number, but cannot be string | number). I think it should be unknown. And if you want type safety, you need to use generics

Comment: This seems to be a limitation of TS; unions/intersections of functions don't get contextual typing. You can put in `string | number` manually, but the compiler does not know how to infer.  The closest existing issue I found for this is [ms/TS#50719](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/50719), but it doesn't seem to be a common scenario (assigning a `[A | B, F1 & F2]` to a `[A, F1] | [B, F2]` and then hoping for inference on `F1 & F2`'s callback param). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?